# Semantic UI nested table shows up in single cell of parent

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create (using Semantic-UI and knockoutjs) a data table where each row has an expandable item (accordion) to show a sub-table of data related to the expanded row.

I have tried to use `colspan="4"` on my sub-table's `<td>` element, to no avail.  No matter what I try, the sub-table seems to only exist within the first column of the parent table.  The jsfiddle below demonstrates the issue better than my description, I'm sure.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/908333/

This may be a simple CSS issue -- I'm no expert -- but nothing I've tried works for me.  I also tried wrapping the sub-table as a `<div>`, but that seemed to break the accordion from collapsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="ui celled table accordion">
      <thead><tr>
       <th ></th>
    <th >ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th >FK1 ID</th>
    <th >FK2 ID</th>
    </tr></thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: arrayVM">
    <tr class="ui title">
      <td><i class="dropdown icon"></i></td>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: fk1id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: fk2id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
      <td colspan="5" class="ui content">
        <table class="ui inverted celled table" style="width:700px">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="ui logo add icon"></i></td>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td>column2</td>
            <td>column3</td>
            <td>column4</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks!